# Parameter adjustment using kerastuneR packet deep neural network

Tags: r, keras-tuner

What is the cause of the following code error?

```
library(magrittr)
x_data <- matrix(data = runif(500,0,1),nrow = 50,ncol = 5)
y_data <-  ifelse(runif(50,0,1) > 0.6, 1L,0L) %>% as.matrix()

x_data2 <- matrix(data = runif(500,0,1),nrow = 50,ncol = 5)
y_data2 <-  ifelse(runif(50,0,1) > 0.6, 1L,0L) %>% as.matrix()

library(keras)
library(tensorflow)
library(kerastuneR)

build_model = function(hp) {
  
  model = keras_model_sequential()
  model %>% layer_dense(units = hp$Int('units',
                                       min_value = 32,
                                       max_value = 512,
                                       step=  32),input_shape = ncol(x_data),
                        activation =  'relu') %>%
    layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'softmax') %>%
    compile(
      optimizer = tf$keras$optimizers$Adam(
        hp$Choice('learning_rate',
                  values=c(1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4))),
      loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
      metrics = 'accuracy')
  return(model)
}
tuner = RandomSearch(
  build_model,
  objective = 'val_accuracy',
  max_trials = 5,
  executions_per_trial = 3,
  directory = 'my_dir',
  project_name = 'helloworld')

tuner %>% search_summary()
tuner %>% fit_tuner(x_data,y_data,
                    epochs = 5, 
                    validation_data = list(x_data2,y_data2))

result = kerastuneR::plot_tuner(tuner)
best_5_models = tuner %>% get_best_models(5)
best_5_models[[1]] %>% plot_keras_model()
```

Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) :
ValueError: Objective value missing in metrics reported to the Oracle, expected: ['val_accuracy'], found: dict_keys(['loss', 'acc', 'val_loss', 'val_acc'])

Comment: Your code runs fine with me with no errors , try update your python packages.

Comment: What is your version of Python and TensorFlow?  I suspect my version is wrong.

Comment: `python3.8` `tensorflow 2.6`